# Difference between Jacke und Mantel

Tags: difference, word-choice

What is the difference between a *Jacke* and a *Mantel*?

Are there any cases in which one could be both?

Are they properly defined or are they *elastic* concepts?

Comment: Don't forget the "Weste". Northerners and southerners can dispute for hours about what a "Weste" is as opposed to a "Jacke" and whether or not "Westen" have sleeves. :-)

Comment: @Chris this is just the case when the "Weste" is made of wool. Otherwise its defined as *bis zur Taille reichendes, **ärmelloses** [...] Kleidungsstück [...]*

(source: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Weste)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are clearly defined:

**Jacke** is jacket, so just a normal jacket, nothing special about it.

**Mantel** is cloak or coat, so actually longer than a normal jacket.

When it comes to length, **Mantel** goes down to the knee or even more.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The difference between a "Jacke" and a "Mantel" is the length.

Comment: @Roman Reiner Du hast Recht, an die Länge des Kleidungsstückes hatte ich gar nicht gedacht. Laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantel): "Der Mantel ist ein der Jacke ähnliches Kleidungsstück, der wesentliche Unterschied besteht in der Länge."

Comment: Not necessarily down to the feet -- mid-leg is also Mantel to me, while Jacke would end shortly after the butt.

Answer (score 11):

They are both fairly well-defined, separate concepts:

> *Jacke* - jacket (light, shorter outerwear)
>   *Mantel* - coat (heavy, longer outerwear)

A *Jacke* is appropriate for mild, autumnal weather and usually is waist-length or shorter. A Mantel is appropriate for cold, winter weather and is usually ankle or knee-length.

This same concept also applies to derivative nouns, such that:

> *Regenjacke* - A (light, shorter) rain jacket
>   *Regenmantel* - A (heavier, longer) raincoat

Also note that *Mantel* also means **cloak, sheath, or covering** and is used in a variety of contexts such as for electrical sheaths on wires, or for ceremonial cloaks, etc.

**Additional Resources:**

> Wikipedia Entry (German): [Mantel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantel)
>
> > *"Der Mantel ist ein der Jacke ähnliches Kleidungsstück, der wesentliche Unterschied besteht in der Länge. Die Differenzierung, ab welcher Länge die Jacke aufhört und der Mantel anfängt, ist von der Epoche und der Mode abhängig."*
>
> Duden Entry: [Mantel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mantel)
>
> > *"längeres Kleidungsstück mit langen Ärmeln, das [zum Schutz gegen die Witterung] über der sonstigen Kleidung getragen wird"*

Comment: There are lots of *Winter-, Anorak-* and *Skijacken* that are appropriate for winter weather (if combined with fitting trousers). Length is really the only criterium to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @Hulk Ah but of course, I hadn't thought too long about the various wintry variations of jackets. Without a doubt, length is the decisive factor.